# get cookies set by javascript using curl

Tags: php, cookies, curl, session-cookies

I'm writing a script that uses curl to fetch the contents of a webpage. I search the headers for `Set-Cookie` to collect the names of all cookies set by the page. The problem is that some cookies are set from within a javascript file loaded into the page and of course these cookies aren't included in the response headers.

So, is there a way to get all cookies from a webpage using curl, including the ones that is generated through javascript?

Currently I'm doing something like this:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, <www.example.com>);
$response = curl_exec($curl);
$http_code = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
if ($http_code == 200) {
  $headers = substr($response, 0, curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE));
  // check headers for all cookies sent in response
}
curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: no. it's not. not unless you want to parse/execute the JS code once you've spidered/slurped down the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cURL isn't going to run javascript, so no, there won't be a way to get those cookies. You'll have to emulate or automate a browser in order to achieve that. Fortunately there are tools to help you. Maybe take a look at [PHP-webdriver](https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver)

Comment: @KristerAndersson take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331938/interpreting-javascript-in-php